# Automatically add imports with ReSharper templates

Tags: resharper, live-templates

I am writing live templates for ReSharper that rely on types defined in an external namespace.

Is there a way to tell it "Add a using directive if needed", so that I don't have to fix that manually after each use

```
/* Template expands to */
var $ListName$ = new List<$Type$>()$END$;

/* But sometimes needs to import */
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Fully qualify your type names, and select "Shorten qualified references".

[image: Live templates]

Comment: What about the using directives needed for extension methods?

Comment: @PPC I fear that this doesn't work with extension methods (with infix invocation). I haven't tested it, but maybe it works with the new R# 9.1 "Source Templates".

Answer (score 2):

Yep, in your template, use the fully qualified type name, e.g.

```
var $ListName$ = new System.Collections.Generic.List<$Type$>();
```

If you then check "Shorten qualified references", ReSharper will insert the text as just `new List<…>();` and automatically add `using System.Collections.Generic;` if it's not already there.